# Salesforce SFDX and Netskope

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, certificates, grant-login-access

Following the deployment of a security solution within our park, Netskope (similar to Zscaler)

We have problems with SFDX CLI and VSCode, indeed we solved a first problem concerning SSL:

[image]

We added the environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to the path of our Netskope Root Certificate,

However we have another error after adding the variable:

[image]

Of course we have no problem if we disable Netskope

Do you know how to fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the actual raw response from the Chrome Console / Network tab?

Comment: Have you looked at this article? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm